# Very Simple Geo targeting

Tags: customization

I would like some very simple and limited Geo targeting functionality.

I want to display a different footer depending on whether the visitor is from US or not. Ideally the code should be something like this:

```
<?php if ( visitor is from usa ): ?>
<?php get_footer('us'); ?>
<?php else: ?>
<?php get_footer('other-countries'); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I would prefer the solution to be as simple and light as possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I personally really like the GEO service provided by [ip-api.com](http://ip-api.com/docs/api:serialized_php)

It is very simple to use and a sample PHP code to grab the `countryCode` would give you what you need very simply. You can do MUCH more and you can read the full doc on it but for your specific needs listed, here is a sample code:

```
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$query = @unserialize(file_get_contents('http://ip-api.com/php/' . $ip));
$geo = $query['countryCode'];
```

The rest is a simple if `$geo == 'US'` do whatever else do something else. That's pretty much it and its very simple to implement and you don't have to install anything. The MaxMind library is good but it can be heavy and difficult to manage for some.

Good luck.

---

### Update 1 [php] (3/5/18)

In response to your email, switching to `JSON` instead is not much different than how it is now. The only line that changes is this:

```
$query = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://ip-api.com/json/' . $ip), true);
```

and if you want to use a callback function, simply this:

```
$query = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://ip-api.com/json/' . $ip . '?callback=<function>'), true);
```

I recommend you use the `true` parameter on `json_decode` to get an array so it is easier to manipulate.

### Update 2 [jquery] (3/5/18)

I just realized that in your email you mentioned jQuery and while I personally would opt for the above PHP method, here is an example of how to use jQuery to achieve the same thing.

```
var ip = ...;
var query = $.getJSON(
    "http://ip-api.com/json/"+ ip,
    function (json) {
        var whatever = json.whatever;
        // where whatever is something that is returned
        // such as status aka json.status
        // look at what is returned to see what you need
    });
```

... means the ip, however you are going to obtain it
no callback should really be necessary as you can just do whatever you want inside the function above and that's it.

Comment: Thanks. Where do I put the first code?

Comment: In any PHP file from which you need to access it to make a decision. For example if you are making this decision early on, then somewhere top level like your header, footer, or index file itself (I prefer the header)

Comment: I tried the code. It needs `$geo == 'US'` in the if statement. Thanks for offering such a fast-loading and simple solution.

Comment: @IXN correct, I was just speaking as general concept, but I see where that might be confusing, I will make the adjustment, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I used this service a long time ago and it was *relatively* painless to set up:
https://github.com/maxmind/geoip-api-php

Once you set it up, you can pull the visitor's country code or name based off their IP address.

Answer (score 1):

I personally really like the GEO service provided by [ipinfo.io developer](https://ipinfo.io/developers)

```
$data = file_get_contents("http://ipinfo.io");
$loc_info = json_decode($data);
$country = $loc_info->country; //get country code

//check visitor country code here.

if ( $country == 'US'):
    get_footer('us'); ?>
else:
    get_footer('other-countries')
endif;
```

[image]

Comment: a code snippet with no explanation is not a useful answer here

Comment: I have added with information.

Comment: Thanks but I get error message: `file_get_contents(http://ipinfo.io): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 429 Too Many Requests`

Comment: Yes, because of this one free on limit. Need to purchase a plan for more request please review site content.